# Kibana 4 setting up passportjs Ldap Authentication

Tags: ldap, passport.js, kibana, kibana-4

How can I setup Ldap authentication for Kibana using  passportJs? I know there's a way to do it using Shield but that is very costly, so I was thinking of doing it using passportJs.

Comment: If it is not possible and if someone adds a proper explanation of why it wouldn't be possible, I would accept that explanation as the answer.